# Updating default values on a mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

In order to update a table and assign a default value on a column, one may use a statement such as:

`UPDATE table SET a = 'value', b = DEFAULT WHERE ISNULL(c)`.

However, the following will not work.

`UPDATE table SET a = IF(FALSE, 'value', DEFAULT)`

Now what do I do when I want to update a column and assign a default value on it when passed to a function statement?

Comment: Is the function updating the record?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table SET a = IF(FALSE, 'value', DEFAULT)' at line 1

Comment: @user2180613 . . . How do you get that error on the second statement when there is no `NULL` in the statement?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry I have changed the example in the meantime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_default), you can use `DEFAULT` in expressions in this form:

```
DEFAULT(col_name)
```

So, your query should be changed to:

```
UPDATE table SET a = IF(FALSE, 'value', DEFAULT(a))
```

This is currently spelled out on the documentation for the [`INSERT` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html), but unfortunately, not for the `UPDATE` statement which is why you may have been stumped:

> You can also use DEFAULT(col_name) as a more general form that can be
>   used in expressions to produce a given column's default value.